# Ruby to_json encode cyrillic into unicode

Tags: json, ruby, string, encoding

I have a hash object with cyrilic text like this

```
payload = {'date': "30",'name': 'Тест','phone': "71234567890",'sum': "0",'offer_id': "1"}
```

I need to convert it to json and send to php api service like this

```
{"date":"30","name":"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442","offer_id":"1","phone":"71234567890","sum":"0"}
```

But `to_json` returns me

```
{"date":"30","name":"Тест","offer_id":"1","phone":"71234567890","sum":"0"}
```

How do I encode cyrilic into unicode in that case? Do I need to pass options to `to_json` method?

Comment: There is zero difference between `"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442"` and `"Тест"`, you might easily check it in the console. Send it as is, everything will be fine.

Comment: That's true, but I need to encode it with md5, and unicode and cyrilic give me diff hashes. And php api I'm working with uses unicode to generate hash, so our md5 sums are different :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There definitely should be a more elegant solution, but with `String#dump` the below would work.

```rb
  payload.to_json.dump.
    gsub('\\"', '"').
    sub(/\A\s*"\s*|\s*"\s*\z/, '')
```

Check:

```rb
require 'digest/md5'
require 'json'


payload = {'date': "30",'name': 'Тест', 'offer_id': "1", 'phone': "71234567890",'sum': "0",}

expected_json = '{"date":"30","name":"\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442","offer_id":"1","phone":"71234567890","sum":"0"}'

dumped_json =
  payload.to_json.dump.
    gsub('\\"', '"').
    sub(/\A\s*"\s*|\s*"\s*\z/, '')

puts expected_json
puts 
puts dumped_json
puts 
puts expected_json == dumped_json


puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest(expected_json)
puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest(dumped_json)
```

Please be aware that there is no guarantee in the order of elements in the JSON, so checking MD5 is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Compare `proper_hash.to_json` and the json (which is a string) from my answer. Like this: `proper_hash.to_json == "#{puts payload.to_json.dump}"`.

Comment: Ain't we talking about the same? Here's repl of what am I doing. Maybe I don't understand you properly. 

https://repl.it/@jakuninoleg/Dump-Test

Comment: I have updated the answer. Apparently `#dump` left leading and trailing double quotes, what I could not even imagine. Sorry for messing the things.

Comment: No problems. Still gotta think what to do with this php mess :/

Comment: SO server had eaten my last edit, I have reposted it.

Comment: Wow, that works, you're a magician :)
But I had to add [0..-2] to the end of the sub method, otherwise you have extra " symbol at the end of the string

Comment: And for the order I just call .sort.to_h